# SSL/TLS operations failing PHP5.6 - curl-ca-bundle.crt & cacert.pem

Tags: php, apache, ssl, curl, xampp

this has been driving me crazy for a couple of weeks now.

I usually do my development on a CentOS 7 box, but recently i've started using Xampp on Windows 10 and using the CentOS box to commit code to & client testing.

Everything works fine on the linux box, but on Windows any SSL/TLS calls are failing, and from what I can tell it's due to the new PHP5.6 feature of verifying peer certificates and host names by default - http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php

I've read just about every how-to guide online, and on SO, and as far as I know I've tried everything, but am getting nowhere.

Please can someone help?!

Extension `extension=php_openssl.dll` is enabled in php.ini, and so is `extension=php_curl.dll`.

I've also downloaded cert files and added the following to my php.ini..

```
curl.cainfo = "‪C:\xampp\php\certs\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
curl.capath = "‪C:\xampp\php\certs\"


openssl.cafile= "‪C:\xampp\php\certs\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
openssl.capath= "‪C:\xampp\php\certs\"
```

The errors I am getting are:

For SMTP calls using TLS:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in W:\libraries\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp.php on line 206
```

For cURL calls:

```
API call to messages/send failed: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: ‪C:\xampp\php\certs\cacert.pem CApath: none
```

The contents of the `C:\xampp\php\certs\` directory is:

```
ca-bundle.trust.crt
cacert.pem
curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

I have restarted Apache, and even tried using curl.exe as a standalone program in command line, which works fine requesting HTTPS domains (not sure if that is relevant, but I tried it anyway!)

I have also tried adding the following to php.ini (and restarting Apache) which has no effect..

```
openssl.verify_peer= false
openssl.verify_peer_name = false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're not using PHP 5.6 instead of the never actually officially released PHP6?

Comment: if you're desperate, just disable it.. curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

Comment: @hanshenrik - ideally looking to solve the issue, plus I'm not calling cURL directly, it's being called used in an API i've integrated, so can't really mess about with the code there. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Does the api offer a direct handle to the curl?

Answer (score 2):

The error message `error setting certificate verify locations` comes from libcurl itself and means it couldn't find or open the CAFile specified.

On Windows, I think it will work if you change the path from:

```
curl.cainfo = "‪C:\xampp\php\certs\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

to

```
curl.cainfo = "‪C:/xampp/php/certs/curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

The same probably goes for OpenSSL but I haven't tested to confirm.

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error, have restarted Apache too :(

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a permissions issue and the certs file wasn't being read - moving the `C:/xampp/php/certs/` folder to another location (in my user directory for instance) solved the problem :)